# format end date of time span using momentjs

Tags: javascript, localization, momentjs

I'm trying to format start and end date of a period.

```
var fromDateAsString = moment("2015-01-01T00:00").format('??');
var toDateAsString = moment("2015-01-02T00:00").format('??');
console.log(fromDateAsString + ' - ' + toDateAsString);
```

Expected result (german locale):

```
1.01.2015 00:00 Uhr - 1.01.2015 24:00 Uhr
```

Solution should work for other locales too.

My Questions:

- end date (1/2/15 00:00) should be displayed as 1.01.2015 24:00
- is there a "short date with time for current locale"
  format available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moment doesn't currently have support for a 24th hour.  Midnight is always the 0'th hour at the beginning of the day.

Other than that, you can get the format you're asking about by combining the short-date locale format specifier with the time-locale specifier.  For example:

```
moment.locale('de');
moment("2015-12-31T13:45").format('l LT') // "31.12.2015 13:45"
```

This will format correctly in other locales:

```
moment.locale('en');
moment("2015-12-31T13:45").format('l LT') // "12/31/2015 1:45 PM"
```